# How to dynamically change MotionLayout transition keyframe value for background color?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have started playing around with `MotionLayout` and noticing that most of documentation shows how to do transitions in xml. I have an issue where I don't know the background color of the app bar until an image has loaded and I have figured out how to set that color in the `ConstraintSet`. However this color also needs to be set in the transition and was curious how one might change the `KeyAttribute` value in the transition dynamically?

```
        <KeyFrameSet>
           
            <!--how to change this key attribute background color dynamically? -->
            <KeyAttribute
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/appbar_background"
                motion:framePosition="90" >
                <CustomAttribute
                    motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
                    motion:customColorValue="@color/green" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/appbar_background"
                motion:framePosition="100" >
                <CustomAttribute
                    motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
                    motion:customColorValue="@color/white" />
            </KeyAttribute>
        </KeyFrameSet>
```

I saw there was a function on `MotionLayout` called `getTransition()`, I'm not sure how to change this background color value with this or if this is even the correct approach in trying to do this?

```
motionLayout.getTransition(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)?.let { transition ->
    //how to change background color at the frame 90 position? or even do it here? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set the background color at the start and end ConstraintSet.

```
 <CustomAttribute
     motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
     motion:customColorValue="@color/white" />
```

needs to be in the  constraint set:
Minimum :

```
<ConstraintSet .... "@id/start"
<Constraint 
  android:id="@+id/appbar_background">
   <CustomAttribute
         motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
         motion:customColorValue="@color/green" 
</Constraint>
    <ConstraintSet .... "@id/end"
<Constraint 
  android:id="@+id/appbar_background">
   <CustomAttribute
         motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
         motion:customColorValue="@color/white" 
</Constraint>
```

At which point you do not need the KeyAttributes
In general KeyFrames are used to modify the interpolation between ConstraintSets

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In my turn I changed

```
<CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="background"
                app:customColorValue="@color/black" />
```

to

```
<CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="background"
                app:customColorDrawableValue="@color/black" />
```